# How to reference to the DOM element of hasClass jquery method?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
 <ul class="    nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#panel1" data-toggle="tab" class="active"><i class="fa fa-info-circle bold_blue"></i>&nbsp;<span class="bold_blue">Graphic User Interface (GUI)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#panel2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-tablet bold_blue"></i>&nbsp;<span class="bold_blue">Sharing</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#panel3" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-signal bold_blue"></i>&nbsp;<span class="bold_blue">Landing Page</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#panel4" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-desktop bold_blue"></i>&nbsp;<span class="bold_blue">Device</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#panel5" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-share bold_blue"></i>&nbsp;<span class="bold_blue">Internet</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

On page load, I would like to add a class to the sister divs.

```
if( $("ul.nav-tabs li").hasClass('active') ){
     $(this).siblings().addClass('disabled');
    }
```

The problem is that the value of $(this) is returning as undefined. Is there is a way to get the referenced DOM element in this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `this` in that context refers to the `window` object, not a DOM element.

```
$("ul.nav-tabs li.active").siblings().addClass('disabled');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ajy61vse/1